# Jquery append element to the new list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to add 'menu' items to the 'animal list' and then append the 'delete button' to the list items by clicking(toggle) the 'Edit button'. Problem is the delete button only adds to the given list item not to the new items that was added. current code can be shown here. 
http://jsfiddle.net/7DP9L/9/

HTML

```
1. Add these items to the list
<div class="menu">                                    
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="addCat">Add_Cat</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="addDog">Add_Dog</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;  
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="addLion">Add_Lion</a>    
</div>
<br />

2. Add/hide delete button from the list
<div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="editBtn">Edit Button</a>
</div>    

<ul id="animal">
    <li><a href="#">Bird</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Snake</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">fish</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.delBtn{
    display:none;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cat = $('<li>Cat</li>');
    var dog = $('<li>Dog</li>');
    var lion = $('<li>Lion</li>');
    var deletebutton = '<input class="delBtn" type="submit" value="delete"/>';

    // Step 1. Add items to the list
    $('#addCat').one("click", function() {
        $(cat).hide().prependTo('ul#animal').fadeIn("slow");
    });

    $('#addDog').one("click", function() {
        $(dog).hide().prependTo('ul#animal').fadeIn("slow");
    });

    $('#addLion').one("click", function() {
        $(lion).hide().prependTo('ul#animal').fadeIn("slow");
    });

    // Step 2. Add/hide delete button from the list items    
    $('ul#animal li').append(deletebutton);

    $('#editBtn').click(function(){
        $('.delBtn').toggle();
    });     



});
```

Comment: ok nice work. Btw what you want to do?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7DP9L/2/  Here you go, btw its "on", not "one" (if its not just fiddle bug). And make sure you have jQuery library referenced.

Comment: @Holybreath: `.one()` is correct if OP only wants the handler to be invoked once.

Comment: @Holybreath jQuery has _one_ method.

Comment: oh yeah , right right right, sorry ;)

Comment: Could you provide a question?!

Comment: sorry I updated the jsfiddle. forgot to include the library

Comment: @Holybreath cookie monster is correct. I only want to invoke once..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not append your delete button with your li ?

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">                                    
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-animal="Cat" class="addAnimal">Add_Cat</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="javascript:void(0)"  data-animal="Dog" class="addAnimal">Add_Dog</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
  <a href="javascript:void(0)"  data-animal="Lion" class="addAnimal">Add_Lion</a>   
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.addAnimal').one("click", function() {
    $('<li></li>')
               .append('<a href="#">'+$(this).data('animal')+'</a>')
               .append(deletebutton)
               .hide()
               .prependTo('ul#animal')
               .fadeIn("slow");
});
```

i also edited a little bit your `html` to propose something more generic. `data-attributes` are really helpful for that.

edit: you should also disable your "add" buttons when your are in "edition mode"

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7DP9L/16/)